# Bluething Board out of sync

Tags: arduino

I have a [Bluething Board from Franzis](https://www.franzis.de/maker/raspberry-pi-arduino-und-mehr/internet-of-things-bluething-board-platine) which I would like to program. It has a ATmega328P processor and in the instructions is written that it has an Arduino Nano board.

The problem I'm having is that as soon as I try to upload any program, it tells me that the connection is not in sync ([see this detailed log](https://paste.ee/p/VhlMt)).

I hope that anyone of you got a similar problem because I could not find anything on the internet. There were some people who had a 0x00-Byte response in which case there is no connection happening between PC and microcontroller. In my case, as you can see in the log file, it attemts to sync ten times but always gets a different byte as a response. Also, the Bluething Board blinks when I try to upload.

PS: I'm using the "AVRISP mkll" programmer, if this is relevant

Edit: There are always the same response-bytes: (attempt 1 to 10)

`0x86` `0x98` `0xf8` `0x9e` `0x86` `0x9e` `0x60` `0x66` `0x9e` `0x06`

Answer (score 0):

Someone with more knowledge helped me and we found the error: The Bluething Board uses the ***old* ATmega328P bootloader**. When I uploaded it with this bootloader selected, everything worked just fine.